# ZK : Loading values into Selectbox from java

Tags: zk

i want to creat a selectbox to load an array of values into it.

I have written the code but the values are not loading into the selectbox so, it is empty. I think, the connection between controller and the view is incorrect. Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

### ZUL Page:

```
<zk xmlns="">

    <window id="win" apply="hw.SalesController">

     <grid sclass="editHeader">
            <columns visible="false">
                <column width="150px"/>
                <column/>
            </columns>
            <rows>
                <row>
                    <cell>
                        Sales Type
                    </cell>
                    <cell>
<!--SELECTBOX-->
                        <selectbox id="salesTypeListbox" model="${$composer.salesModel}"
                           >
                            <template name="model">
                                <listitem label="${each}" />
                            </template>
                        </selectbox>                        

                    </cell>    
                </row>
            </rows>            
        </grid>   
    </window>
</zk>
```

### SalesController.java:

```
public class SalesController extends SelectorComposer<window> {

    private ListModelList<String> salesModel = new ListModelList<String>(SalesHeader.getSalesType());

}
```

## SalesHeader.java:

```
public class SalesHeader {

        public static List<String> getSalesType() {
                return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"BU-0", "BU-1", "BU-2", "BU-3"});
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

The first error is

> Property 'salesModel' not found on type [your composer class]

This is because you are missing a getter-method in your composer:

```
public ListModelList<String> getSalesModel() {
   return salesModel;
}
```

The second error is regarding the `listitem` element in your selectbox's template. It's causing:

> Listitem's parent must be Listbox, not Selectbox

You can overcome that by simply using `each` or a `label` element in your template:

```
<template name="model">
    ${each}
</template>
```

[Here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/26g7kqd/1-SO-Quesetion-33819068) you can find a working ZKFiddle example.

Comment: The above fixed the error. how do i store value and label in the selectbox as do it HTML combobox?